# How to get thumbnail_id in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the below code in my child theme function.php and I am getting all the term id's. But get_woocommerce_term_meta function is not returning any values. I am using the latest version of Woocommerce and Wordpress. Also, the same code working fine in another template file without any issues. I am not sure what am i missing here.

```
add_action('init', 'remove_home_page_sections',0);
add_action('homepage', 'custom_storefront_product_categories',20);

function remove_home_page_sections(){
    remove_action( 'homepage','storefront_homepage_content',10);
    remove_action( 'homepage','storefront_product_categories',20);
}

function custom_storefront_product_categories(){
    $cat_args = array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'parent'     => 0,
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',);

    $terms = get_terms($cat_args);
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );

        // get the medium-sized image url
        echo $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'medium' );
        echo "-->".$term->term_id."--[".$thumbnail_id."]";

       }
}
```

Comment: Please add `shop_catalog` instead of `medium` in getting attachment then just `print_r($image)` so you can check what you are getting.

Comment: @raju_eww thanks for your response. But the problem is with get_woocommerce_term_meta and its not returning a thumbnail_id. don't know why

Comment: first check that in backend have you add images for category and also `print_r($terms)` so you can get all terms with its data.

Comment: @raju_eww there you are. Thank you. I don't know what to call myself!! I didn't set the image.